# Page Transition Style Like Flipboard on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, flip, flipboard

I'm searching how to create the flip effect on a wp8 application like the Flipboard style : www.flipboard.com.
could you help me how to proceed to create this effect?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment using Telerik's SlideView control. You can set a Flip transition. You can download the [Telerik sample application](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=fd55f526-d6f7-df11-9264-00237de2db9e) and try it out. The phone controls are only $99. Even better is to use [Nokia Developer Offers](http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-developer-offers). You get Telerik's phone controls, as well as Infragistics controls, a DevCenter account and BugSense tracking for $99. I know it's not free, but how much is your time worth creating all the controls you get from this?

NOTE: I am not affiliated with any of the above companies.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [How to Perform a Card Flip Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320322/how-to-perform-a-card-flip-animation/20344626#20344626)

I have told how to make FlipAnimation, un projections menu there are also other effects that affect XYZ axes - your effect is quite simple.

But if you wan't a whole page transition then i think you should NOT use pages, but use different Views on one page.